# Flick IMG src attribute to simulate blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie here! I'm sorry if this is very simple.

I have two images of a person, eyes open and eyes shut. The eyes closed file has a 'b' at the end, so:

'/images/person.png' (eyes open)
'/images/personb.png' (eyes closed)

What I'd like is to switch the src on 'mouseenter' very quickly, so that the image looks like it's blinking twice in quick succession.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks fellas!

Comment: Could you post any relevant code/markup please. The solution shouldn't be too hard, but it will be virtually impossible to provide anything without seeing your current setup/structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in HTML5:

[Live example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59BJC/)

Just replace the `background-color` by `background-image:url('your_url');` in your CSS.

### HTML

```
<div id="your_flipping_img"></div>
```

### JS

```
$('#your_flipping_img').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $('#your_flipping_img').addClass('animate');
})

$('#your_flipping_img').bind('mouseout', function(){
    $('#your_flipping_img').removeClass('animate');
})
```

### CSS

```
#your_flipping_img{
    background-color:#efefef;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}

.animate{
    -webkit-animation: flicking .5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: flicking .5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flicking {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: #efefef;}
    50%  {background-color: red;}
    100% {background-color: #efefef;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes flicking {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: #efefef;}
    50%  {background-color: red;}
    100% {background-color: #efefef;}
}
```

Comment: He wants the image to blink twice in close succession on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to probably have to do that with javascript.

Assuming your image is something like `#blinkingimage`:

```
function blinkImage(image,num) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    image.src = 'images/personb.png';
    setTimeout(function() {
      image.src = 'images/person.png';
    }, 50); // Set this to however long you want the blink to be, in milliseconds
  }, 50); // Set this to however long you want the delay to be, in milliseconds      
}

$('#blinkingimage').hover(function() {
  blinkImage($(this),1);  //You said you want it to blink twice, so you'll need to call blinkImage twice
  setTimeout(function() {
    blinkImage($(this),2);
  }, 100); // Set this to twice the length of one blink call
});
```